# Nuget Package not installing in framework 4.6.1 VS 2017

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

Error       Could not install package 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.1'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Installing in Visual Studio 2017

Comment: .Net Core 5 and .Net Framework 4.6 aren't the same thing. You want to install EntityFramework. I think the current version is something like 6.4 or so (december 2020). PM> Install-Package EntityFramework

Answer (score 1):

`Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` targets .NET Standard 2.1, which *basically* means it will only work on .NET Core 3.1 or above; .NET Framework (any version) **does not** support .NET Standard 2.1; some versions of .NET Framework support .NET Standard 2.0 (at least, sort-of), but *that isn't enough*.

Two options:

1. move away from .NET Framework (hugely preferred option) - ideally to .NET 5.0 or .NET Core 3.1 (at time of writing)
2. use an older version of Entity Framework; [EF 6.4.4](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.4.4) works down to .NET 4.0, or (as noted by Hostel in comments) EF Core 3.1.10 *may* work on .NET Framework 4.6.1

Comment: `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` `3.1.10` depends on .`NET Standard 2.0`, so can be used with `.NET Framework` **4.6.1+**.

Comment: @Hostel updated (with credit), but: frankly, 4.6.1 only *sort of* supports .NET Standard 2.0 - I've seen *so many problems* with .NET Framework's hacked-in support for .NET Standard; it is ... hit and miss